# looking for a c# bitwise operation for bitarray

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to perform a bitwise operation on a BitArray that would result in:

1010
    0011
= 1000

So whenever the first bit is set and the corresponding bit is not set (1-0) it returns 1. all other scenarios (0-0,1-1,0-1) result in 0.

How can I achieve this, with or without a bitwise operation?

Performance is critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

Assume ba1 is your first BitArray, and ba2 is your second.

ba1.And(ba2.Not())

should leave ba1 in the state you are looking for in O(2N) time. (but both of your BitArrays will have been modified - more work - and time - required if you need to preserve the source BitArrays by making copies of them).

Answer (score 3):

If performance is critical, you might want to consider not using BitArray at all given the [memory and performance overhead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx), and instead use BitVector32 or perform operations directly on the underlying bytes:

```
 byte a = 0x3a;     // 0011 0101
 byte b = 0xa3;     // 1010 0011
 byte r = a & (~b); // 0001 0100
```

If you find the performance of BitArray is suitable for your needs, then there is no need to prematurely optimize; however, if you find performance is unsuitable, you may want to consider replacing BitArray.